# make sql dump with stdin like syntax to update table with condition

Tags: postgresql

when making dump file with pg_dump command this performace is very fine but in dump is only create alter and inserts with syntax

COPY table1 (id, name) FROM stdin;
1   developer's portal
...
.

I want to make with this syntax sql dump where table will updated
for example
update table1 set name ='hello' where id=1

with pg_dump syntax

Comment: You will have to write your own tooling to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This script will do, although, for simplicity's sake, it assumes the table's primary key is the first field:

```
table=table1
psql -Atc "with a as (select attrelid::regclass::text rel, attnum i, quote_ident(attname) col from pg_attribute where attrelid='$table'::regclass)
select 'select format(\$\$update '||rel||' set '||string_agg(col||'=%s', ', ' order by i)||'\$\$, '||string_agg('quote_nullable('||col||')', ',' order by i)||')||\$\$ where '||
       (select col||'=\$\$||quote_nullable('||col||')||\$\$;\$\$ from '||rel from a where i = 1) from a where i > 1 group by rel" |\
psql -At
```

If you're using PostgreSQL 9.5+, then you could use `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT UPDATE ...` instead:

```
table=table1
psql -Atc "with a as (select attrelid::regclass::text rel, attnum i, quote_ident(attname) col from pg_attribute where attrelid='$table'::regclass)
select 'select format(\$\$insert into '||rel||'('||string_agg(col, ',' order by i)||
       ') values ('||string_agg('%s', ',')||
       ') on conflict ('||(select col from a where i=1)||') do update set '||
       string_agg(case when i > 1 then col||'=excluded.'||col end, ', ' order by i)||';\$\$, '||
       string_agg('quote_nullable('||col||')', ',' order by i)||') from '||rel from a where i > 0 group by rel" |\
psql -At
```

Comment: I created file and wrote this code and assigned blabla instead %s

after runing it shows result

update table1 set code=bla where id='1';
update table1 set code=bla where id='2';
update table1 set code=bla where id='3';
update table1 set code=bla where id='4';

but really no result saved